# $timeout not working in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using `$timeout` in my controller but its not working!

```
app.controller("Friendsrequests",['$http','$log','$location','$timeout','$scope', function($http,$log,$location,$timeout,$scope){
//getting base url of application
this.baseUrl = function() {
        var base_url = window.location.origin;

        var pathArray = window.location.pathname;
        return base_url;
    //  return base_url+pathArray;
                };
// assigning to a variablebase_url('login/f_request');
var ThroughUrl = this.baseUrl()+'/keon/login/f_request';


//declare a variable
var ata = this;
ata.notifications = [ ] ;
ata.counts=' ';
//sending ajax request
 function getNotifications()
{
$http({method: 'POST', url: ThroughUrl,})
.success(function(data) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available

//assign data to the variable
ata.notifications=data;
ata.counts =data.length;

  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });

}

$timeout(function() {
    getNotifications();
}, 1000);

}]);
```

- what is the issue .

Comment: What does not working mean?  Is it failing with an error, just not being called, etc.?

Comment: the console is empty no error the controller successfully pass data to view but its not repeat the function (ajax call)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Just replace

```
$timeout(function() {
    getNotifications();
}, 1000);
```

with

```
$interval(function() {
   getNotifications();
},1000);
```

Check [Angular's doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: yes now is working but i have this error in the console Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: Note that there is an [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service. I'm guessing the answer explaining why no $interval existed in August of 2013 is just outdated now :)

Comment: can i have to inject the $apply into the controlller?

Comment: @user3636439 if you use $interval - no

Comment: @user3636439 instead inject `$interval` (you shouldn't have to inject `$apply` ... it's a function on the `$scope`). The main reason to use `$interval` instead of `setInterval()` is that it won't cause you headaches in unit tests... plus you don't need to use `$apply()` b/c Angular will call it for you as needed when using $interval :)

Comment: It works, out of the box! just replaced. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

while calling timeout in angularJS just remove Parentheses or brackets ()

```
$timeout(getNotifications, 1000);
```

**getNotifications** function will call after 1000 milliseconds(One second)